# Tableau making the viz height to be the same as on the server via API

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following options to make the viz show properly in my container. Width wise it is showing up proper. My issue is the height, i have specified it as 500px at this time. How can i make the height to be the same as that on the tableau server?

```
var vizDivObject = document.getElementById('tableauVizDiv');
var options = {
                    width: vizDivObject.offsetWidth,
                    height: "500px", //vizDivObject.offsetHeight,
                    hideTabs: true,
                    hideToolbar: true
                };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, we are supporting tablets and desktop browsers. The following worked for me since all of our vizs are dashboards, along with option `width: vizDivObject.offsetWidth`.

```
var workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
var activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
if (activeSheet.getSheetType() === 'dashboard') { //worksheet or dashboard
                    //alert(activeSheet.getName());
                    activeSheet.changeSizeAsync({
                        behavior: tableauSoftware.SheetSizeBehavior.AUTOMATIC
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Tableau JavaScript API reference manual I can't see a way to get the height of the workbook before you create the viz. The viz will be created to fill the area you define.  If you don't set a default height in either the div or the initializeViz() function, then the default is 600px.
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v8.1/server/en-us/js_api_ref.htm

To get the default size used by tableau I open the tableau workbook on the tableau server and then under "Share -> Embed Code" you will find the size used by the tableau server. I then use this use in the div

```
<div id="tableauVizDiv" style="width: 1304px; height: 862px;"></div>
```